# Mitsubishi logo builder

Tags: java, extension-methods

I have created a Mitsubishi logo builder that takes input from the logo.txt file and uses those ints/chars to create however many logos that are identified in the logo.txt file.

I just feel that my code is very repetitive and I would like to clean it up in terms of cutting it into separate methods instead of repeating over and over. Are there any recommendations on how to clean this up? I would appreciate any and all feedback. Or even just a starting point.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    try {
        input = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("config.txt"));
        //initialize ithe variable's input and output
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found.");
        System.exit(0);

    }

    int size = Integer.parseInt(inputStream.nextLine());
    int numLogos = Integer.parseInt(inputStream.nextLine());
    char letter1 =  inputStream.next().charAt(0);
    char letter2 =  inputStream.next().charAt(0); 

    for(int bee = numLogos; bee > 0; bee--){ 
        for(int y = 0; y < size; y++) { 

            for(int x = 0; x < y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter2);
            }
            for(int x = 0; x < size - y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter2);
            }
            for(int x = 0; x < y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter2);
            }
            for(int x = 0; x < size - y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter2);
            }

            for(int x = size; x > y; x--) {
                System.out.print(letter2);
            }
            for(int x = 0; x < y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter1);
            }
            for(int x = 0; x < y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter1);
            }
            for(int x = size; x > y; x--) {
                System.out.print(letter2);
            }

            for(int x = 0; x < y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter2);
            }
            for(int x = 0; x < size - y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter2);
            }
            for(int x = 0; x < y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter2);
            }
            for(int x = 0; x < size - y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter2);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }           
        for(int y = 0; y < size; y++) {
            for(int x = 0; x < y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter2);
            }
            for(int x = 0; x < size - y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter2);
            }
            for(int x = 0; x < y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter2);
            }
            for(int x = 0; x < size - y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter2);
            }

            for(int x = 0; x < y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter2);
            }            
            for(int x = 0; x < size - y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter1);
            }
            for(int x = 0; x < size - y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter1);
            }
            for(int x = 0; x < y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter2);
            }

            for(int x = 0; x < y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter2);
            }
            for(int x = 0; x < size - y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter2);
            }
            for(int x = 0; x < y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter2);
            }
            for(int x = 0; x < size - y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter2);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        for(int y = 0; y < size; y++) {
            for(int x = size; x > y; x--) {
                System.out.print(letter2);
            }
            for(int x = 0; x < y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter1);
            }

            for(int x = 0; x < y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter1);
            }
            for(int x = 0; x < size - y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter1);
            }

            for(int x = size; x > y; x--) {
                System.out.print(letter1);
            }
            for(int x = 0; x < y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter2);
            }

            for(int x = 0; x < y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter2);
            }            
            for(int x = 0; x < size - y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter1);
            }

            for(int x = 0; x < y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter1);
            }
            for(int x = 0; x < size - y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter1);
            }

            for(int x = 0; x < y; x++) {
                System.out.print(letter1);
            }
            for(int x = size; x > y; x--) {
                System.out.print(letter2);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably you need to replace `inputStream` with `input`

Answer (score 4):

You can reduce duplication in your code step-by-step by moving repetitive code into separate methods.

**1. Move the code that prints one logo into a separate method:**

Introduce new method that prints exactly one logo of a given size and then call it in a loop

```
for(int bee = numLogos; bee > 0; bee--) { 
    printLogo(size);
}
```

By the way, increasing loop counters are easier to read most of the time. Use them whenever possible:

```
for(int bee = 0; bee < numLogos; bee++) { 
    printLogo(size);
}
```

I would also suggest either renaming `bee` to something meaningful (`logoIndex`) or replacing it with generic counter variable (`i`).

**2. Merge loops that print the same letter**

Consecutive loops that print the same letter, like these:

```
for(int x = 0; x < y; x++) {
    System.out.print(letter2);
}
for(int x = 0; x < size - y; x++) {
    System.out.print(letter2);
}
```

, are redundant. You need to merge them into one:

```
for(int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
    System.out.print(letter2);
}
```

**3. Introduce a method(s) for letter printing**

Currently, your code uses two types of loops for printing:

```
//type 1: prints a given number of letters
for(int x = 0; x < someLimit; x++) {
     System.out.print(someLetter);
}

//type 2: prints a number of letters necessary to leave space at the end
for(int x = size; x > numbersAtTheEnd; x--) {
    System.out.print(someLetter);
}
```

You can create two separate methods for these operations:

```
//Example for the first type of loop
public static void printLetter(char letter, int count) {
    for(int x = 0; x < count; x++) {
        System.out.print(letter);
    }
}

public static void printLetterUntil(char letter, int size, int left) {
    for(int x = size; x > left; x--) {
        System.out.print(letter);
    }
}

//then call this method repeatedly:
printLetter(letter2, y);
printLetter(letter2, size-y);
printLetter(letter2, y);
```

I'd suggest transforming the second type to the first one. It seems that `printLetterUntil(letter, size, left)` is equivalent to `printLetter(letter, size-left)`, but you'll need to check my logic for off-by-one errors.

**4. Figure out a pattern**

After previous steps have been completed your main printing method will look approximately like this:

```
static void printLogo(int size) {
    for(int y = 0; y < size; y++) { 
        printLetter(letter2, someCount);
        printLetter(letter1, anotherCount);
        printLetter(letter2, yetAnotherCount);
        //skipped similar lines
        System.out.println();
    }
    for(int y = 0; y < size; y++) { 
        //second part
        printLetter(letter2, someCount);
        printLetter(letter1, anotherCount);
        //...
    }
    for(int y = 0; y < size; y++) { 
        //third part 
        printLetter(letter2, someCount);
        printLetter(letter1, anotherCount);
        //...
    }
}
```

These loop bodies look terribly similar to each other. All of them print alternating sequences of `letter2` and `letter1`. To get rid of them you can introduce a method that takes an array of numbers and prints alternating sequences of letters:

```
 public static void printAlternatingSequence(char letter1, char letter2, int... segments) {
      for(int i=0; i<segments.length; i++) {
           \\print letter2 for even indices and letter1 for odd
           char currentLetter = i%2==0 ? letter2 : letter1;
           printLetter(currentLetter, segments);
      }
 }
```

Notice the use of varargs parameter. This way you don't have to explicitly create an array.

You can call this method like this:

```
static void printLogo(int size) {
    for(int y = 0; y < size; y++) { 
        printAlternatingSequence(letter1, letter2, someCount, anotherCount, ...);
    }
    for(int y = 0; y < size; y++) { 
        printAlternatingSequence(letter1, letter2, someCount, anotherCount, ...);
    }
    for(int y = 0; y < size; y++) { 
        printAlternatingSequence(letter1, letter2, someCount, anotherCount, ...);
    }
}
```

**5. Turn parameters into fields.**

Notice that some values are used in several methods (`letter1`, `letter2`, `size`). Instead of passing them as an argument in every method you can introduce a new class, declare fields for these values and pass them in a constructor.

Example:

```
public class MitsubishiLogoPrinter {
    private final int size;
    private final char letter1;
    private final char letter2;

    public MitsubishiLogoPrinter(int size, char letter1, char letter2) {
        this.size = size;
        this.letter1 = letter1;
        this.letter2 = letter2;
    }

    public void printLogo() {
        //skipped implementation
    }

    private void printAlternatingSequence(int... segments) {
        //skipped implementation
    }
}
```

**Further improvements.**

Take a look at the lengths of segments printed. Probably, there is a usable pattern there as well. If you can represent the length of each segment as `f(size, lineNumber) = k*size+l*lineNumber` then you can store quotients in a constant array and main printing method will just loop through it.